# How can i change language in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs

I want to change the language of my angular app from english to other language. I don't want to use localization. Is there a way to do it with google translate or any other api?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-translate: [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

it's easy to implement and lets you use .json files for every language that you want to implement.